# Why is the kafka consumer consuming process for 3 times and doesn't consume after?

Tags: apache-kafka

kafka consumer is not reading message from the topic.I don't understand the problem-was working fine earlier.

The messages gets processed for 3 times.Fourth time it doesn’t process.
If I try after 1 hour-it again get processed for 3 times and doesn’t work after.

Why does this happen?

Below is the code

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "XXX", havingValue = "true")
public class EventListener {


  @KafkaListener(id = "XX", topics = "#{'${topic'}")
  public void consumeMessageEvent(Event messageEvent, ConsumerRecord<String, ?> record) {

  }

  }
```

Comment: Please share your code and any other relevant details, thx

Comment: Attached the code

Comment: I feel like you are still not giving us much to work on here - think from the perspective of people who know nothing about what you have implemented and what you are experiencing - so relevant details might include information about how you are producing messages - are you producing continuously but you only consume 3 and that's it When you try again after 1 hour, do you mean you restart the application? Is it the same 3 messages? What is your broker setup - is this local, how many brokers? How are producers and consumers configured?

Comment: You might want to run a console-consumer on the topic from earliest message to see if there are more than 3 messages on the topic, ie whether the unexpected behaviour is down to producer or consumer. Once you narrow it down to that you can start to home in on potential causes